# Applying both a rotation and color adjustment to a GDI DeviceContext causes the colours to be reset

Tags: vb.net, gdi

I am using API calls to transform a Bitmap object. I have various physical transformations (rotation, flipping, scaling, displacement) as well as some colour adjustments (inversion, brightness and contrast)

Everything works fine except for when I use the rotation or shear transformations in combination with the colour adjustment. In that case the colours revert to the original image.

The interesting thing about this problem is that it seems to be dependent on the off-diagonal factors (eM12 and eM21 below) in the XForm matrix. For example, here is the rotation matrix:

```vb
Public Sub RotateClockwise(Radians As Single)
    With XFormMatrix
        .eM11 = Cos(Radians)
        .eM12 = Sin(Radians)
        .eM21 = -Sin(Radians)
        .eM22 = Cos(Radians)
        .eDx = 0
        .eDy = 0
    end with
end sub
```

Whenever eM12 or eM21 are non Zero then my colours go missing! The same problem happens for example with the shear transformation:

```vb
Public Sub Shear(ShearFactorX As Single, ShearFactorY As Single)
    With XFormMatrix
        .eM11 = 1
        .eM12 = ShearFactorX
        .eM21 = ShearFactorY
        .eM22 = 1
        .eDx = 0
        .eDy = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is the sub (abbreviated) where I apply the Transformation and set the colour adjustment

```vb
Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "GDI32.dll" (ByVal hDC As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateDIBSection Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, pBitmapInfo As BITMAPINFO, ByVal un As Long, ByVal lplpVoid As Long, ByVal handle As Long, ByVal dw As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "GDI32.dll" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWorldTransform Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByRef lpXform As xForm) As Long
Private Declare Function SetColorAdjustment Lib "GDI32.dll" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByRef lpCA As ColorAdjustment) As Long
Private Declare Function StretchBlt Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal hSrcDC As Long, ByVal xSrc As Long, ByVal ySrc As Long, ByVal nSrcWidth As Long, ByVal nSrcHeight As Long, ByVal dwRop As Long) As Long

Private Sub TransformAndDraw()
'Initialise objects
BufferDC = CreateCompatibleDC(0)
BgBuffer = CreateDIBSection(hDC:=BufferDC, pBitmapInfo:=bmi, un:=DIB_RGB_COLORS, lplpVoid:=0&, handle:=0&, dw:=0&)
SelectObject BufferDC, BgBuffer

'Define the transformation matrices
SetWorldTransform hDC:=BufferDC, lpXform:=XFormMatrix

' Apply this colour adustment to the Buffer DC
SetColorAdjustment hDC:=BufferDC, lpCA:=NewAdjust

'load picSource into the Buffer and apply scaling factor
    StretchBlt hDC:=BufferDC, _
               x:=0, _
               y:=0, _
               nWidth:=srcBmp.bmWidth * xsize, _
               nHeight:=srcBmp.bmHeight * xsize, _
               hSrcDC:=srcHDC, _
               xSrc:=0, _
               ySrc:=0, _
               nSrcWidth:=srcBmp.bmWidth, _
               nSrcHeight:=srcBmp.bmHeight, _
               dwRop:=vbSrcCopy

'Paint the UserControl surface with the Buffer

'reset and delete objects
End Sub
```

To summarise my question: **is there some way I can use both *SetWorldTransform* and *SetColorAdjustment* when using non-zero values for the off-diagonal factors in my XForm transformation?**

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution. I separated the physical transformations and the colour adjustements into two separate calls to StretchBlt. In between I reset the Xform matrix within the Image-Buffer so that it was not present during the colour adjustment.

In the first call an external picture source is loaded into the Buffer and stretched according to the Xform matrix .
In the second call the buffer is painted onto itself in order to apply the colour adjustment.

```
Private Sub TransformAndDraw()
    'Initialise objects
    BufferDC = CreateCompatibleDC(0)
    BgBuffer = CreateDIBSection(hDC:=BufferDC, pBitmapInfo:=bmi, un:=DIB_RGB_COLORS, lplpVoid:=0&, handle:=0&, dw:=0&)
    SelectObject BufferDC, BgBuffer

    'extract the original transform-settings
    OldGraphicsMode = SetGraphicsMode(hDC:=BufferDC, iMode:=GM_ADVANCED)
    GetWorldTransform hDC:=BufferDC, lpXform:=OldMatrix
    ' Get the current (default) colour adjustment
    OldStretchMode = SetStretchBltMode(hDC:=BufferDC, nStretchMode:=HALFTONE)
    OrigAdjust.caSize = Len(OrigAdjust)
    GetColorAdjustment hDC:=BufferDC, lpCA:=OrigAdjust

    'Define the transformation matrices
    SetWorldTransform hDC:=BufferDC, lpXform:=XFormMatrix

    'load picSource into the Buffer and apply scaling factor
    'hSrcDC:=srcHDC
    StretchBlt hDC:=BufferDC, _
               x:=0, _
               y:=0, _
               nWidth:=srcBmp.bmWidth * xsize, _
               nHeight:=srcBmp.bmHeight * xsize, _
               hSrcDC:=srcHDC, _
               xSrc:=0, _
               ySrc:=0, _
               nSrcWidth:=srcBmp.bmWidth, _
               nSrcHeight:=srcBmp.bmHeight, _
               dwRop:=vbSrcCopy

    'revert the transform settings, these can conflict with the colour adjustment
    SetWorldTransform hDC:=BufferDC, lpXform:=OldMatrix
    SetGraphicsMode hDC:=BufferDC, iMode:=OldGraphicsMode

   ' Apply the colour adustment to the Buffer DC
    SetColorAdjustment hDC:=BufferDC, lpCA:=NewAdjust

    'now apply a second call to StretchBlt, this time painting the buffer with itself!
    'hSrcDC:=BufferDC!
    StretchBlt hDC:=BufferDC, _
               X:=0, _
               Y:=0, _
               nWidth:=UserControl.ScaleWidth, _
               nHeight:=UserControl.ScaleHeight, _
               hSrcDC:=BufferDC, _
               xSrc:=0, _
               ySrc:=0, _
               nSrcWidth:=UserControl.ScaleWidth, _
               nSrcHeight:=UserControl.ScaleHeight, _
               dwRop:=vbSrcCopy

    'now revert the colour adjustment settings
    SetStretchBltMode hDC:=BufferDC, nStretchMode:=OldStretchMode
    SetColorAdjustment hDC:=BufferDC, lpCA:=OrigAdjust

    'Paint the UserControl surface with the Buffer
    BitBlt hDestDC:=UserControl.hDC, _
           X:=0, _
           Y:=0, _
           nWidth:=UserControl.ScaleWidth, _
           nHeight:=UserControl.ScaleHeight, _
           hSrcDC:=BufferDC, _
           xSrc:=0, _
           ySrc:=0, _
           dwRop:=vbSrcCopy

    'Delete objects!
    DeleteDC BufferDC
    DeleteObject BgBuffer
    UserControl.Refresh
End Sub
```